# What is the physical size of the Lightning connector?

Tags: lightning, iphone

The title has it... What is the physical size of the new Lightning connector? That is, what's the size of the tip of the connector that gets plugged into the device? I want to use this information for comparison of physical size of micro USB and Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any precise measurements of the connector itself, but you can see from [these iPhone 5 blueprints](http://www.businessinsider.com/iphone-5-blueprint-details-2012-9?op=1) (which come from Apple for case manufacturers) that the width of the area the connector goes is 9.05mm (including the plastic housing).

I used a hires image from [iFixit's iPhone 5 teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone-5-Teardown/10525) to get an estimate that the metal tip is about 84% of the width of the plastic housing, which works out to **about 7.6mm**, give or take. Using the same methodology, I'd estimate the height of the metal connector to be about 1.4mm.

Comment: And what about the height of the dock?

Comment: Added that to my answer. About 1.4mm.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best information:
Depth   0.35 in,
Height  0.79 in,
Width   1.18 in,
Product Weight  0.14 oz

From http://mobile.websurplus.com/product?18560152